# Sorted array to BST

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, methods, binary-search-tree

I am trying to make a BST from sorted array. I am aware of the logic how to do it, i just need a way to get middle point of both sides of root.
I am using custom imports which have setRightChild(), and getRightChild() and so on, shouldn't be too hard to figure out what those mean. This is as far as i got:

```
    public static <E> BTree<E> taulukostaPuu(ArrayList<E> L) {

     BTree<E> T = new BTree<E>();
     buildBST(L,T);
     return T;
}       
     private static <E> void buildBST(ArrayList<E> L,  BTree<E> T) {
         int n = L.size();
         if (n == 0)
             return;

         E x = L.get((L.size()/2) + (L.size() % 2));
         T.setRoot(new BTreeNode<E>(x));

     }
   }
```

I would like to keep this structure throughout. Any suggestions how to proceed?

I have gotten this far, but i am working with elements so not sure how to make this work.

```
  public static <E> BTree<E> taulukostaPuu(ArrayList<E> L) {

     BTree<E> T = new BTree<E>();
     buildRecursively(L,L.get(0),L.get(L.size()-1),T);
     return T;
}       

private static <E> void buildRecursively(ArrayList<E> L,E start,E end,BTree<E> T){

if (start.compareTo(end) < 0)
    return;
E x = L.get((L.size()/2) + (L.size() % 2));
int mid = (L.size() / 2);
T.setRoot(new BTreeNode<E>(x)); 
T.setLeftChild(buildRecursively(L, start, mid - 1));
T.setRightChild(buildRecursively(L, mid + 1, end));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a method to build the tree recursively.

The method return type/args would be something like `BTreeNode<E> buildRecursively(ArrayList<E> list, int start, int end)`, and each call would do something like this:

- Calculate the middle index
- Create the middle node
- Build the left subtree by providing the appropriate `start` and `end` args
- Build the right subtree similarly to the left (but, you know, on the other side)
- Attach the left and right subtrees to the middle node
- Return the middle node

The exact order isn't important.

The hard part will be avoiding [off-by-one errors](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096). ;)